# Confused about this line in a script

Tags: linux, shell, sh

Just start getting familiar with linux, got confused about this line in a script

```
get_ip(){
    local IP=$( ip addr | egrep -o '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' | egrep -v "^192\.168|^172\.1[6-9]\.|^172\.2[0-9]\.|^172\.3[0-2]\.|^10\.|^127\.|^255\.|^0\." | head -n 1 )
    [ -z ${IP} ] && IP=$( wget -qO- -t1 -T2 ipv4.icanhazip.com )
    [ -z ${IP} ] && IP=$( wget -qO- -t1 -T2 ipinfo.io/ip )
    [ ! -z ${IP} ] && echo ${IP} || echo
}
```

I`m guessing this is supposed to get my ip address?

Could you guys explain in detail to me?

This line `ip addr | egrep -o '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' | egrep -v "^192\.168|^172\.1[6-9]\.|^172\.2[0-9]\.|^172\.3[0-2]\.|^10\.|^127\.|^255\.|^0\." | head -n 1`

Comment: Did you try running it observe what it does?

Comment: which line? you posted scriptlet with 6 lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a combination of `regEx` for checking if the `IPv4` address is in the right syntax (the first one) and checking the valid `IP` does not belong to a specific range.

The `regEx`

> `[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}`

Matches 4 octets which could be of length from `1-3` consisting of numbers `0-9`, separated by a `.`. This ensures any `IP` address are filtered out from processing.

The second one with the `-v` flag for invert-match, i.e. meaning exclude the ones of this type,

> `^192\.168|^172\.1[6-9]\.|^172\.2[0-9]\.|^172\.3[0-2]\.|^10\.|^127\.|^255\.|^0\.`

Excludes `IPs` starting with,

- `192.168`
- `172.16`, `172.17`, `172.18`, `172.19`
- `172.20`, `172.21`, `172.22`, `172.23` upto `172.29`
- `172.30`, `172.31`, `172.32`
- `10.`
- `127.`
- `255.`
- `0.`

and `head -n 1` is irrelevant here as the above command operates on only single line throughout.

As for the rest of the script goes

```
# This line checks if variable containing the IP address is empty and if it is
# empty i.e. the condition `[ -z ${IP} ] ` turned out to be true set the IP
# address to the value obtained from `wget` output
[ -z ${IP} ] && IP=$( wget -qO- -t1 -T2 ipv4.icanhazip.com )

# same as above
[ -z ${IP} ] && IP=$( wget -qO- -t1 -T2 ipinfo.io/ip )

# with a '!' symbol it means the variable is not empty just print value
# to stdout or (||) print just an empty output (just echo)
[ ! -z ${IP} ] && echo ${IP} || echo
```

Comment: What`re the rest of that script mean, btw? :)

Comment: @xtronaltic: Am not sure what you mean. Tried to mean that with `-o` flag will work only on the IP address and the negative match too, so,`head -1` was irrelevant.

Comment: [ -z ${IP} ] && IP=$( wget -qO- -t1 -T2 ipv4.icanhazip.com )
    [ -z ${IP} ] && IP=$( wget -qO- -t1 -T2 ipinfo.io/ip )
    [ ! -z ${IP} ] && echo ${IP} || echo  what`re those? @Inian

Comment: I can see OP asking for clarity on the line involving the `regex` alone

Comment: So the entire script is trying to find my server`s ip address, right? @Inian

Comment: @xtronaltic: Makes sense now?

Comment: @xtronaltic: Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

Let disassemble it into segments:

`ip addr` - show information about your interfaces

`egrep -o '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'`

> -o, --only-matching
>                 Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.

This attempts to match IP addreses from output of `ip addr`

`egrep -v "^192\.168|^172\.1[6-9]\.|^172\.2[0-9]\.|^172\.3[0-2]\.|^10\.|^127\.|^255\.|^0\."`

This excludes IP addeses like 192.168.*.*, 172.16.*.*-172.19.*.* etc ...

`head -n 1`
This restrict output to only first line

So entire command effectively tries to find IP address on your interfaces which is not from private ranges.